# .htaccess rewriting error - writing non-friendly parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When I request

`http://localhost/project/mycontroller/`

the URL rewrites to

`http://localhost/project/mycontroller/?l=mycontroller`

The .htaccess (my guess) is concatenating  the same `GET` variable to the URL.

Note 1 : `l` is actually my `$_GET` variable and everything works fine, even if I mess up with the non-friendly URL.

Note 2 : Firstly I thought it could be some redirecting that my framework could be doing so I put a php  `exit();` on the first line of the `index.php` and it continued to rewrite, so I thought it could be the .htaccess file.

Have any of you  solved this before?

**.htaccess**

```
<Files magic>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php5
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
Header append Vary User-Agent       

#?l=local -> /local
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)$ ?l=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/$ ?l=$1 [NC,L]

#?l=local&sl=sublocal -> local/sublocal
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)$ ?l=$1&sl=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/$ ?l=$1&sl=$2 [NC,L]

#?l=local&sl=sublocal&cod=1 -> local/sublocal-1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&cod=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&cod=$3 [NC,L]

#?l=local&sl=sublocal&cod=1 -> local/sublocal/var
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&var=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&var=$3 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Address bar:

[image: address bar]

Comment: What is location your .htaccess? Are there more rule or any other .htaccess any where in your system?

Comment: The file is located on the root folder: `localhost/project/.htaccess`, there is another `.htaccess` on the admin folder: `localhost/project/admin/.htaccess`

Comment: ok is this full `/project/.htaccess` content? And is `/project/mycontroller/` a real directory?

Comment: Yes, it is the full content, and it is a real directory @anubhava

Comment: Hmm doesn't look like it pasted full content since `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` is not closed in the code above.

Comment: the next line is `</IfModule>`  I swear :B hehe I only erased it accidentally.

Comment: Have you tried `RewriteBase /project/`above your rules?

Comment: Just tried @stslavik, still concatenating.

Comment: Just pulled this into MAMP and dumped the server vars... Worked fine... `["REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"]=> string(14) "l=mycontroller" ["REDIRECT_URL"]=> string(17) "/tsg/mycontroller"` are what I would expect in this case... I think you've got a different problem than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<Files magic>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php5
</Files>
Header append Vary User-Agent       
DirectorySlash off

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /project/

#?l=local -> /local
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ ?l=$1 [QSA,L]

#?l=local&sl=sublocal -> local/sublocal
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ ?l=$1&sl=$2 [QSA,L]

#?l=local&sl=sublocal&cod=1 -> local/sublocal-1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&cod=$3 [QSA,L]

#?l=local&sl=sublocal&cod=1 -> local/sublocal/var
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ ?l=$1&sl=$2&var=$3 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: It became fully functional also but still concatenating.

screenshot : [link](http://imgur.com/bKK7Usq)

Comment: Try it in a different browser. Does `/project/mycontroller/` also have a .htaccess?

Comment: Oh man, it was **Chrome**. Tried on FF and Opera and it was perfect, no concatenating.

Comment: In Chrome also you can just clear browser cache to make it work. Glad it worked out.

Comment: Cleared all the data but still getting the error, seems like it's a new issue on this version/OS `35.0.1916.153/elementaryOS`, I'll report it now. Thank you again :]